# How do I group Windows Form radio buttons?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button

How can I group the radio buttons in Windows Form application (a lot like ASP.NET's radiobuttonlist!)?

So I can switch between each case chosen from the options.

Comment: You can take a look at [Windows Forms RadioButtonList](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41355419/3110834)

Comment: See screenshot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46424314/984780

Answer (score 480, accepted):

Put all radio buttons for a group in a container object like a `Panel` or a `GroupBox`.  That will automatically group them together in Windows Forms.

Comment: @mohammadsadeghsaati The question was about the Windows Forms RadioButton, it does not expose a GroupName property.

Comment: @UweB what if I cant add group boxes and panels due to any problem let say I don't have much space on my form. Then?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqib it's impossible because panels can be zero-sized. I mean panels with invisible borders and without margins are the same as plain form. Just use right panel - TableLayoutPanel if you should group in table etc

Comment: This no longer seems to be the case. I created a test project that has nothing except a Form with a Panel and 2 Radiobuttons inside. Clicking the unchecked one does nothing. I have confirmed that they are inside the Panel because deleting the Panel also deletes the Radiobuttons.

Answer (score 44):

Look at placing your radio buttons in a [GroupBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.aspx).

Comment: GroupBox is totally unrelated to radio buttons. Any container will do.

Answer (score 37):

You should place all the radio buttons of the group inside the same container such as a `GroupBox` or `Panel`.

Comment: It gets complicated when you've got layers of nested panels, such as when you are trying to do [something that looks like this](http://thewindowsclub.thewindowsclubco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/syskey-2.jpg). The radio buttons conflict with their parents.

Answer (score 27):

I like the concept of grouping RadioButtons in WPF. There is a property `GroupName` that specifies which RadioButton controls are mutually exclusive (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.aspx).

So I wrote a derived class for WinForms that supports this feature:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Use.your.own
{
    public class AdvancedRadioButton : CheckBox
    {
        public enum Level { Parent, Form };

        [Category("AdvancedRadioButton"),
        Description("Gets or sets the level that specifies which RadioButton controls are affected."),
        DefaultValue(Level.Parent)]
        public Level GroupNameLevel { get; set; }

        [Category("AdvancedRadioButton"),
        Description("Gets or sets the name that specifies which RadioButton controls are mutually exclusive.")]
        public string GroupName { get; set; }

        protected override void OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnCheckedChanged(e);

            if (Checked)
            {
                var arbControls = (dynamic)null;
                switch (GroupNameLevel)
                {
                    case Level.Parent:
                        if (this.Parent != null)
                            arbControls = GetAll(this.Parent, typeof(AdvancedRadioButton));
                        break;
                    case Level.Form:
                        Form form = this.FindForm();
                        if (form != null)
                            arbControls = GetAll(this.FindForm(), typeof(AdvancedRadioButton));
                        break;
                }
                if (arbControls != null)
                    foreach (Control control in arbControls)
                        if (control != this &&
                            (control as AdvancedRadioButton).GroupName == this.GroupName)
                            (control as AdvancedRadioButton).Checked = false;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Checked)
                base.OnClick(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            CheckBoxRenderer.DrawParentBackground(pevent.Graphics, pevent.ClipRectangle, this);

            RadioButtonState radioButtonState;
            if (Checked)
            {
                radioButtonState = RadioButtonState.CheckedNormal;
                if (Focused)
                    radioButtonState = RadioButtonState.CheckedHot;
                if (!Enabled)
                    radioButtonState = RadioButtonState.CheckedDisabled;
            }
            else
            {
                radioButtonState = RadioButtonState.UncheckedNormal;
                if (Focused)
                    radioButtonState = RadioButtonState.UncheckedHot;
                if (!Enabled)
                    radioButtonState = RadioButtonState.UncheckedDisabled;
            }

            Size glyphSize = RadioButtonRenderer.GetGlyphSize(pevent.Graphics, radioButtonState);
            Rectangle rect = pevent.ClipRectangle;
            rect.Width -= glyphSize.Width;
            rect.Location = new Point(rect.Left + glyphSize.Width, rect.Top);

            RadioButtonRenderer.DrawRadioButton(pevent.Graphics, new System.Drawing.Point(0, rect.Height / 2 - glyphSize.Height / 2), rect, this.Text, this.Font, this.Focused, radioButtonState);
        }

        private IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control, Type type)
        {
            var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

            return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl, type))
                                      .Concat(controls)
                                      .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This came in handy for me in a situation where I needed RadioButtons in a group inside a TableLayoutPanel - thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to use this class for one of my own forms, but having trouble getting the control to display on top of a group box (as if it is the group box's title). It is meant to serve as the top-level radio button (*id est*, the group for this radio button is a panel at the root of the form and the group box is a sibling). Is there any example code on how to use this class to achieve that?

Comment: I would write `IEnumerable<Control> arbControls = null;` instead of using dynamic. The `var` masks it even more, and that's why I normally use only explicit types in my code. Otherwise, very good job, and thanks a lot for sharing this! +1

Answer (score 14):

Radio button without panel

```
public class RadioButton2 : RadioButton
{
   public string GroupName { get; set; }
}

private void RadioButton2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton2 rb = (sender as RadioButton2);

    if (!rb.Checked)
    {
       foreach (var c in Controls)
       {
           if (c is RadioButton2 && (c as RadioButton2).GroupName == rb.GroupName)
           {
              (c as RadioButton2).Checked = false;
           }
       }

       rb.Checked = true;
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //a group
    RadioButton2 rb1 = new RadioButton2();
    rb1.Text = "radio1";
    rb1.AutoSize = true;
    rb1.AutoCheck = false;
    rb1.Top = 50;
    rb1.Left = 50;
    rb1.GroupName = "a";
    rb1.Click += RadioButton2_Clicked;
    Controls.Add(rb1);

    RadioButton2 rb2 = new RadioButton2();
    rb2.Text = "radio2";
    rb2.AutoSize = true;
    rb2.AutoCheck = false;
    rb2.Top = 50;
    rb2.Left = 100;
    rb2.GroupName = "a";
    rb2.Click += RadioButton2_Clicked;
    Controls.Add(rb2);

    //b group
    RadioButton2 rb3 = new RadioButton2();
    rb3.Text = "radio3";
    rb3.AutoSize = true;
    rb3.AutoCheck = false;
    rb3.Top = 80;
    rb3.Left = 50;
    rb3.GroupName = "b";
    rb3.Click += RadioButton2_Clicked;
    Controls.Add(rb3);

    RadioButton2 rb4 = new RadioButton2();
    rb4.Text = "radio4";
    rb4.AutoSize = true;
    rb4.AutoCheck = false;
    rb4.Top = 80;
    rb4.Left = 100;
    rb4.GroupName = "b";
    rb4.Click += RadioButton2_Clicked;
    Controls.Add(rb4);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

**Put radio buttons inside GroupBox** (or other panel)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

All radio buttons inside of a share container are in the same group **by default**.
Means, if you check one of them - others will be unchecked.
If you want to create independent groups of radio buttons, you must situate them into different containers such as `Group Box`, or control their *Checked* state through *code behind*.

Answer (score 5):

`GroupBox` is better.But not only group box, even you can use `Panels` (`System.Windows.Forms.Panel`).

- That is very usefully when you are designing Internet Protocol version 4 setting dialog.(Check it with your pc(windows),then you can understand the behavior)

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot put them into one container, then you have to write code to change *checked* state of each **RadioButton**:

```
private void rbDataSourceFile_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rbDataSourceNet.Checked = !rbDataSourceFile.Checked;
}

private void rbDataSourceNet_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  rbDataSourceFile.Checked = !rbDataSourceNet.Checked;
}
```

Comment: This will put you into an infinite loop,,,