# Make a group of Radio buttons [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net

I have two groups of Radio buttons but they  are put in one group box , so how can i separate them without creating another group box , so if i choose an option from group 1 i will still be able to choose option from group 2 ?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178240/how-do-i-group-windows-form-radio-buttons

Comment: The solution for the above link is to put them in separated group boxes , but in my case i can't do it because it will disrupt the GUI . Edit never mind , the Panel doesn't appear in the GUI. Thank you for your Help

Comment: OK sure, I have posted an answer to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to disrupt with group boxes, use Panels `(System.Windows.Forms.Panel)`. You won't see the border but the radio buttons will work independently.

Answer (score 2):

Radio buttons will act as though they are all in one group unless separated.

You do that with **Panels** or **Group Boxes**

The difference is **Group Boxes** are visible whereas **Panels** are invisible.

[image: Radio Buttons in Panel]

^ Here, the lower 3 radio buttons are in a **Panel** to separate them from the upper 3 buttons.