# Uncheck checkboxes by checking other checkbox using C#

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes (C#) and I want if the user check one checkbox then unckeck all other checkboxes except the last selected,or he can check them all (he must check one or all).
I use visual studio C#

Comment: Are you using win Forms, WPF or web?

Comment: Are you building a webforms/mvc/winforms/wpf app?

Comment: why don't you use a radio button list?

Comment: @RicardoAppleton, because you cannot check them all

Comment: What have you tried so far? @RicardoAppleton can't because he wants the user to be able to check all of the options.

Comment: `if the user check one checkbox`: do you mean 1 very specific checkbox? While the other checkboxes do not uncheck their siblings when you click on them?

Comment: post your code. what have you tried so far?

Comment: It would help to internally manage an array or list which contains references to the checkboxes in questions. Furthermore events would have to be disabled during assignment of the other checkboxes.

Comment: Checkbox is a GUI element in computing that can be used in Windows Forms, WPF, Silverlight, HTML and many other platforms/frameworks. There is nothing specific to C# about it. So first, you need to specify your platform. Also, if your user is allowed to select only one option, then you should be using radio buttons instead of checkboxes. **Edit after you add Visual Studio to the question:** Specifying that you use Visual Studio doesn't provide what kind of application you're developing, because all of the ones I wrote above can be developed in Visual Studio.

Comment: Checkbox may not be the best UI element for this task.  Consider radio buttons or drop down list that contain all values plus an additional value for "All".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I group Windows Form radio buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178240/how-do-i-group-windows-form-radio-buttons)

Answer (score 2):

Use RadioBoxes instead, but include an option for "All of the above".

If you don't want to do that then you need to specify your platform you are developing in. Most likely you would add an event handler on the click event and check every box manually to see if it's checked or not.