# Separate Pairs of radio buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two options contained in a groupbox. But the radio buttons'  scope being applied on

the four of them so only one selection is possible...

[image]

Tried putting each pair in a groupName but that only works in asp.net

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I group Windows Form radio buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178240/how-do-i-group-windows-form-radio-buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx)

> When the user selects one option button (also known as a radio button) within a group, the others clear automatically. All RadioButton controls in a given container, such as a Form, constitute a group. **To create multiple groups on one form, place each group in its own container, such as a GroupBox or Panel control**.