# How can I make the radio buttons independent?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

In my WinForm, I have 4 radio buttons in the same *GroupBox*

How can I make the 2 radio buttons circled in orange independent of the 2 other radio buttons circled in green?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Use different container for each group. The two at top in a panel, the two at the bottom in another panel.

Comment: Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178240/how-do-i-group-windows-form-radio-buttons?rq=2).

Comment: Thank you, do I have to put them in a container? there is no other solution?

Comment: Yes, you have to put each group in a different container; this is how RadioButton works. Unless you want to make your life harder for no reason, and set AutoCheck property of them all to false, and then handle CheckedChanged event of them manually, and check/uncheck other item of group manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two panels to surround the two radion buttons, like this:

[image]

The effect is as follows:

[image]