# Change the color of a small circle (dot) contained within the radio button to be red?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, radio-button

How do I change the color of a small circle (dot) contained within the radio button to be red in Winform Application use VB.NET or C#?

Regard & Thanks,
Dewi

==========================================================
I will share, may be useful to others. This program works.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class Form1

Public Class MyRadioButton
    Inherits RadioButton

    Private m_OnColor As Color
    Private m_OffColor As Color

    Public Sub New(ByVal On_Color As Color, ByVal Off_Color As Color)
        m_OnColor = On_Color
        m_OffColor = Off_Color
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
        BackColor = Color.Transparent
    End Sub

    Public Property OnColor() As Color
        Get
            Return m_OnColor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            m_OnColor = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property OffColor() As Color
        Get
            Return m_OffColor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            m_OffColor = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)

        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

        Dim dotDiameter As Integer = ClientRectangle.Height - 17
        Dim innerRect As New RectangleF(1.8F, 7.8F, dotDiameter, dotDiameter)

        If Me.Checked Then
            g.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(OnColor), innerRect)
        Else
            g.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(OffColor), innerRect)
        End If

        g.DrawString(Text, Font, New SolidBrush(ForeColor), dotDiameter + 17, 1)
    End Sub

End Class


Dim objRadio As New MyRadioButton(Color.Blue, Color.Red)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    objRadio.Location = New Point(100, 100)
    objRadio.Visible = True
    Me.Controls.Add(objRadio)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If objRadio.Checked Then
        objRadio.Checked = False
    Else
        objRadio.Checked = True
    End If
End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408175/third-party-controls-for-a-radio-button-list-in-winforms) a winforms example of an owner drawn listbox simulating a list of radiobuttons that you could use for what you want.

**Edit:** [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ScrollingTextControlArtic.aspx) is a more in-depth Winforms custom control example.

Comment: I'm not sure much of that code is applicable -- the drawing is done by `ControlPaint.DrawRadioButton(e.Graphics, rect, ButtonState.Checked);`.  How would you change this to draw a red circle?

Comment: You can draw whatever you want.  Replace that line of code with the code to draw a red cicle with the e.Graphics.  Look here for a more in-depth custom control example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ScrollingTextControlArtic.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reference, I managed to make it, I draw a circle above a circle of radio button. Also thanks to @justin. I will be share may be useful to other. See above for more details.

Answer (score 7):

I took the OP's VB code as a base and with a bit of MSDN help on using the [PathGradientBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.pathgradientbrush.aspx) came up with this derrived class for C#.  The green and red buttons as seen in the image below are using my code, the two blue ones are the regular version.

[image: Form1 - Displaying Coloured Radio Buttons]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class ColouredRadioButton : RadioButton
    {
        // Fields
        private Color m_OnColour;
        private Color m_OffColour;
        private Rectangle m_glint;
        private Rectangle m_circle;
        private PathGradientBrush m_flareBrush;
        private Pen m_outline;

        // Properties
        public Color OnColour
        {
            get
            {
                return m_OnColour;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((value == Color.White) || (value == Color.Transparent))
                    m_OnColour = Color.Empty;
                else
                    m_OnColour = value;
            }
        }
        public Color OffColour
        {
            get
            {
                return m_OffColour;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((value == Color.White) || (value == Color.Transparent))
                    m_OffColour = Color.Empty;
                else
                    m_OffColour = value;
            }
        }

        // Constructor
        public ColouredRadioButton()
        {
            // Init
            m_circle = new Rectangle(2, 5, 7, 7 /*Magic Numbers*/);
            m_glint = new Rectangle(3, 6, 4, 4  /*Magic Numbers*/);
            m_outline = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 1F /*Magic Numbers*/);

            // Generate Glint
            GraphicsPath Path = new GraphicsPath();
            Path.AddEllipse(m_glint);
            m_flareBrush = new PathGradientBrush(Path);
            m_flareBrush.CenterColor = Color.White;
            m_flareBrush.SurroundColors = new Color[] { Color.Transparent };
            m_flareBrush.FocusScales = new PointF(0.5F, 0.5F/*Magic Numbers*/);

            // Allows for Overlaying
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }

        // Methods
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Init
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            // Overlay Graphic
            if (this.Checked)
            {
                if (OnColour != Color.Empty)
                {
                    g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(OnColour), m_circle);
                    g.FillEllipse(m_flareBrush, m_glint);
                    g.DrawEllipse(m_outline, m_circle);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (OffColour != Color.Empty)
                {
                    g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(OffColour), m_circle);
                    g.FillEllipse(m_flareBrush, m_glint);
                    g.DrawEllipse(m_outline, m_circle);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you're curious and want the code for the big red ball that I was using it to test out the brush features, here you go...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            int Offset = 25;
            int BoxSize = 100;
            int GlintSize = (int)((double)BoxSize * ((double)3 / (double)4));
            Rectangle Circle = new Rectangle(Offset, Offset, BoxSize, BoxSize);
            Rectangle Glint = new Rectangle(Offset, Offset, GlintSize, GlintSize);

            //Debug
            //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), Circle);
            //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.BlueViolet), Glint);

            //Generate Glint
            GraphicsPath P = new GraphicsPath();
            P.AddEllipse(Glint);
            PathGradientBrush FlareBrush = new PathGradientBrush(P);
            FlareBrush.CenterColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
            Color[] colors = { Color.Transparent };
            FlareBrush.SurroundColors = colors;

            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0)), Circle);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(FlareBrush, Glint);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 1F), Circle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This strict "Magic numbers" for m_circle and m_glint positioning are not universal. Using of different fonts or autosize=false makes the colored circle be not centered.

Comment: @Andmark `Y` of `m_circle` is `Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((Height - 7) / 2))`. For `m_glint` it is always one higher.