# Windows Forms RadioButton List - Bind Enum Property to RadioButton

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

Let's say I got few radiobuttons and some custom object as datasource.

As example

```
public enum SomeModeType
{
    firstMode = 10,
    secondMode = 20,
    thirdMode = 30
}

public class MyCustomObject:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private SomeModeType _mode;
    public SomeModeType Mode
    {
        set { _mode = value; }
        get { return _mode; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

How to bind this object property (if its possible) to 3 different radiobuttons with something like:

If `radiobuttonOne` checked - object property `mode` sets to `firstMode`

If `radiobuttonTwo` checked - object property `mode` sets to `secondMode`

If `radiobuttonThree` checked - object property `mode` sets to `thirdMode`

etc etc

Or its better to use events for this?

P.S.
I know how to use events but its overwhelmed to create event by event like `rb1chnaged`, `rb2changed`, ..., `rb100changed`, isnt it?

P.P.S.

MerryXmas!

Comment: When you are declaring the enum type it's just one entry. You need a collection to bind to radio button list. Try declaring `List<SomeModeType>' as property and fill it with each member of enum

Comment: @AnupSharma but how thats helps?
I mean, why not just bind radiobutton to it like - if you choose 1st then field value is becoming `firstMode`, in case of 2nd - it rewrite field value to `secondMode`

Comment: I shared a `RadioButtonList` control [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41355419/3110834).

Comment: It has data-binding support and you can use this control like a `ListBox`. To do so, it's enough to bind it to the property of your model, and then set the data-source of the control simply this way: `radioButtonList1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(YourEnumType));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each value of the enum, you need to create a `RadioButton` and bind its `Checked` value to `Mode` property of data source. Then you need to use `Format` and `Parse` event of `Binding` to convert `Mode` value to suitable value for `Checked` property and vise versa.

**Example - RadioButton List using FlowLayoutPanel**

For example put a `FlowLayoutPanel` control on your form and then in `Load` event of `Form` write following code. The code will add `RadioButton` controls to the flow layout panel dynamically and performs data-binding:

```
var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeModeType)).Cast<object>()
    .Select(x => new { Value = x, Name = x.ToString() }).ToList();
enumValues.ForEach(x =>
{
    var radio = new RadioButton() { Text = x.Name, Tag = x.Value };
    var binding = radio.DataBindings.Add("Checked", dataSource,
        "Mode", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    binding.Format += (obj, ea) =>
    { ea.Value = ((Binding)obj).Control.Tag.Equals(ea.Value); };
    binding.Parse += (obj, ea) =>
    { if ((bool)ea.Value == true) ea.Value = ((Binding)obj).Control.Tag; };
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(radio);
});
```

In above example, `dataSource` can be a `MyCustomObject` or a `BindingList<MyCustomObject>` or a `BindingSource` which contains a `List<MyCustomObject>` in its `DataSource`.

**Another alternative - RadioButton List using Owner-draw ListBox**

As another option you can use an owner-draw `ListBox` and render `RadioButton` for items. This way, you can bind `SelectedValue` of `ListBox` to `Mode` property of your object. The `dataSourcs` in following code can be like above example. Put a `ListBox` on form and write following code in `Load` event of form:

```
var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeModeType)).Cast<object>()
    .Select(x => new { Value = x, Name = x.ToString() }).ToList();
this.listBox1.DataSource = enumValues;
this.listBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.listBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", dataSource,
        "Mode", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
this.listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
this.listBox1.ItemHeight = RadioButtonRenderer.GetGlyphSize(
    Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero),
            RadioButtonState.CheckedNormal).Height + 4;
this.listBox1.DrawItem += (obj, ea) =>
{
    var lb = (ListBox)obj;
    ea.DrawBackground();
    var text = lb.GetItemText(lb.Items[ea.Index]);
    var r = ea.Bounds;
    r.Offset(ea.Bounds.Height, 0);
    RadioButtonRenderer.DrawRadioButton(ea.Graphics, 
        new Point(ea.Bounds.Location.X, ea.Bounds.Location.Y + 2), r, text,
        lb.Font, TextFormatFlags.Left, false,
        (ea.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected ?
        RadioButtonState.CheckedNormal : RadioButtonState.UncheckedNormal);
};
```

**Screenshot**

You can see both solutions in following image:

[image]

```
var list = new List<MyCustomObject>() { 
    new MyCustomObject(){ Mode= SomeModeType.firstMode},
    new MyCustomObject(){ Mode= SomeModeType.secondMode},
    new MyCustomObject(){ Mode= SomeModeType.thirdMode},
};
this.myCustomObjectBindingSource.DataSource = list;
var dataSource = myCustomObjectBindingSource;
```

**Note**

After answering this question, I created and shared a `RadioButtonList` control in this post: [WinForms RadioButtonList doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015411/winforms-radiobuttonlist-doesnt-exist).

It has data-binding support and you can use this control like a `ListBox`. To do so, it's enough to bind it to the property of your model, and then set the data-source of the control simply this way:

```
radioButtonList1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(YourEnumType));
```

Comment: well,interesting, but there is no more simle way for it? ._.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, there is not a more simple way unless you encapsulate all logic in a single control and name it something like `RadioButtonList`.

Comment: Another alternative (which is not more simple at all) is using an owner-draw Listbox. I'll share it too.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I got only 2 different modes situation atm, so I will keep all things simple in my current app but thats interesting approach, will keep in mind!