# Dynamic creating radiobuttons and arange them inside form

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button, dynamic-controls

I'm creating dynamically N radio buttons on form on this way:

```
 private void CreateRadioButton()
    {
        int rbCount = 40;

        System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton[] radioButtons = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton[rbCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < rbCount; ++i)
        {
            radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton();
            radioButtons[i].Text = Convert.ToString(i);
            int x = 514 + i*37;
            int y = 20;
            radioButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x,y);
            radioButtons[i].Size = new Size(37, 17);
            this.Controls.Add(radioButtons[i]);
        }
    }
```

In this case the radiobuttons are all created in one row but i need to arrange them in multiple rows inside specific region. Is it possible? What approach to use for this kind of problem?

Comment: Or FlowLayoutPanel

Comment: Or [RadioButtonList](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41355419/3110834).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fix your code without the suggested ways in the comments

```
private void CreateRadioButton()
{
    int rbCount = 40;
        int numberOfColumns = 8;
        var radioButtons = new RadioButton[rbCount];
        int y = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < rbCount; ++i)
        {
            radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton();
            radioButtons[i].Text = Convert.ToString(i);
            if (i%numberOfColumns==0)  y += 20; 
            var x = 514 + i%numberOfColumns * 37;
            radioButtons[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
            radioButtons[i].Size = new Size(37, 17);
            this.Controls.Add(radioButtons[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: This is just I needed. So simple. Thnx a lot.