# How can I prevent a RadioGroup from trying to set SelectedItem on Focus?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, radio-group

I have a WinForms RadioGroup that is populated with enum values. My problem is when the control obtains focus, it tries to update the selected item with `System.DBNull`, which is not a valid value for an enum, and I end up getting the exception :

> Object of type 'System.DBNull' cannot be converted to type 'MyNamespace.MyEnumType'

I have a custom RadioGroup class which contains the following code for adding items and getting/setting the selected value :

```
/// <summary>
/// sets the items, using reflection to get the display member and value
/// </summary>
public void SetItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> values, string valueMember, string displayMember)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);

    PropertyInfo displayProperty = t.GetProperty(displayMember);
    PropertyInfo valueProperty = t.GetProperty(valueMember);

    if (displayProperty == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Property {0} is not found on class {1}", displayMember, t.FullName), "displayMember");

    if (valueMember == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Property {0} is not found on class {1}", valueMember, t.FullName), "valueMember");

    Properties.Items.Clear();

    foreach (var val in values)
    {
        object desc = displayProperty.GetValue(val, null);
        Properties.Items.Add(new RadioGroupItem(valueProperty.GetValue(val, null), desc == null ? string.Empty : desc.ToString()));
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// accessor for the selected value
/// </summary>
public object SelectedValue
{
    get { return GetSelectedValue(); }
    set { SetSelectedValue(value); }
}


private object GetSelectedValue()
{
    if (SelectedIndex < 0 || SelectedIndex >= Properties.Items.Count)
    {
        if (DataBindings.Count > 0 && DataBindings["SelectedValue"] != null)
            return DataBindings["SelectedValue"].DataSourceNullValue;
        else
            return null;
    }

    return Properties.Items[SelectedIndex].Value;
}

private void SetSelectedValue(object selectedItem)
{
    SelectedIndex = FindSelectedValue(selectedItem);
}

private int FindSelectedValue(object value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Properties.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        object val = Properties.Items[i].Value;

        if ((val != null && val.Equals(value)) || (val == null && value == null))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Here's how it is initialized from the code behind file :

```
myRadioGroup.SetItems<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>>(
    new List<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>>() 
    {
        new KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>(MyEnum.VALUE_A, "Value A"), 
        new KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>(MyEnum.VALUE_B, "Value B")
    },
"Key", "Value");

// adds the binding
myRadioGroup.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("MyPropertyName", myDataSource, "SelectedValue", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, MyEnum.NONE));
```

I am unclear exactly why I am getting this exception when I call

```
myRadioGroup.Focus();
```

The GotFocus event gets hit, and the SetSelectedValue method gets called and returns a normal `null` value. The only thing I can think of is the `GetSelectedValue` shows `DataSourceNullValue` as System.DBNull despite setting it to `MyEnum.NONE` in constructor, but even if I correct that in debug mode it still gives me the same exception.

Also according to the [MSDN page about this binding constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158047(v=vs.110).aspx)

> [The null value parameter] sets the property to the specified value when a DBNull is returned from the data source.

These are the only place I can see a reference to DBNull.

Is there a way to either fix this exception, or prevent the RadioGroup from trying to update the datasource when it gets focus?

Comment: What's `RadioGroup`?

Comment: Take a look at [RadioButtonList](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41355419/3110834). The post contains an example showing how to use it with enum.

Comment: @RezaAghaei As the link you provided says, `RadioButtonList` is a WebForms control, not a WinForms control. That is not a suitable solution for the control library I am working on.

Comment: See my answer which I provided a windows forms control ;) It's in fact a single-select `ListBox` which shows radio button near items. So it has reliable built-in support for data-binding.

Comment: @RezaAghaei That's not a bad idea, but I'm working on a control library that is also built on another third-party control library, so I wanted a solution specifically for RadioGroup. It might be worth looking into some other time though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a solution... the `Binding` constructor sets the `.NullValue` while I need to set the `.DataSourceNullValue`

```
// adds the binding
Binding b = new Binding("MyPropertyName", myDataSource, "SelectedValue", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, MyEnum.NONE);
b.DataSourceNullValue = MyEnum.NONE;
myRadioGroup.DataBindings.Add(b);
```

According to [this MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dchandnani/2005/08/15/data-binding-what-are-nullvalue-and-datasourcenullvalue-properties/)

> `DataSourceNullValue` specifies what value of the data source is considered a null value and also **specifies what value should be written back to the data source for a null value**.

The default is `System.DBNull`, so it appears to be trying to write a null value as `System.DBNull`, which is not valid for an Enum.