# Is there a way to control all radio buttons through one control? Instead of passing a control for each radio button (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button, groupbox, selectedindex

I am currently creating an online shop on winform in c#.

At the moment I am creating a 'shopping basket' related textbox where if a user clicks on a particular radio button the textbox shows the description of the product in the text box.

I have grouped my radio buttons in a group box and would like to know whether there is anything equivalent to a *'SelectedIndex'* command for all radio buttons? Thanks.

Comment: Subscribe all radio buttons to the same `CheckedChanged` event.

Comment: @DangerZone Would you be able to give an example of this please? p.s. more than one radiobutton can be selected at one time. Thank you!

Comment: If more than one can be selected at once, you should not include them in the same group box together. Use checkboxes instead.

Comment: Take a look at [RadioButtonList](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41355419/3110834) for Windows Forms. It's in fact a `ListBox` which its items are rendered like radio buttons. So you can use its `DataSource`, `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember`, `SelectedIndex`, `SelectedItem` and so on.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Is the RadioButtonList able to be used in winforms?

Comment: In the linked post I've created a `RadioButtonList` for Windows Forms. I described about it in previous comment and in thee linked post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply subscribe all radio buttons to the same event. Then you can act on which is checked and act accordingly instead of having duplicate code for each button.
Below is a simple example that set a text box's `Text` property to display which is checked.

**Form class**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void radioButtons_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do whatever you need to do here. I'm simple setting some text based off
        //the name of the checked radio button.

        System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton rb = (sender as System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton);
        textBox1.Text = $"{rb.Name} is checked!";
    }
}
```

**In the .designer.cs file**

```
//Note that the EventHandler for each is the same.
this.radioButton3.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButtons_CheckedChanged);
this.radioButton2.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButtons_CheckedChanged);
this.radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButtons_CheckedChanged);
```

Comment: This could work, is there a way where I could have the values in the textbox in a format of a list? So the user clicks on say 3 radio buttons, this would then create a list of 3 products within the textbox?

I feel as if I may have complicated this so if there is not another way, im gonna have to look into using buttons instead. Thanks!

Comment: @TheBiz - First, like I mentioned in my comment on the question itself, if more than one can be selected, choose something other than radio buttons. If they are in the same area on your form, they are intended to only have 1 selected at a time. Otherwise a checkbox is better UX. But to answer your question, yes, just make the textbox multiline, and in the event, build the text based on what is checked.

Comment: Okay, this is working perfectly for me as I have categorized the products so radio buttons is working efficiently. However, I have used your code along with some of my own which does input a value in the textbox, but it shows the 'design name' instead of the actual product. I have used classes to define my products, how would I input this so when I click on a radio button it shows the product rather than the design name of the button? Thanks (Sorry if this is a really simple question)

Comment: @TheBiz if the product is the text of the radio button, simply use the `.Text` property instead of `.Name`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to select more than one radiobutton at a time, I suggest you to use checkboxes instead of radiobuttons. You can assign all their events to the same single event and control which of the checkboxes are checked.

```
    private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox checkBoxControl = (CheckBox) sender; // You can use this variable to see which one of the checkbox is checked.
    }
```