# How to use Radio Buttons in WindowsFormsApplications? How to check if changed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a small program that will output a string to aid in awarding financial aid scholarships. Scholarships have a type, may or may not have a tier, and if they are "transfer" scholarships, must be either 4 semesters, 6 semesters, or 8 semesters.

I'm new to using Windows Forms Applications, so please keep the answers as simple as possible since I am working on beginner projects.

(Please excuse me if I use the wrong terminology here, but I will describe as best I can what I've tried)

I need to "access" the radio buttons and check to see if they have been ticked. I also have no idea how to update to see if it has been changed.

I have all of my code in comboBox1_SelectIndexChained, and I am guessing that I will need to break this up into different methods such as radiobutton1.CheckChanged, etc.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Object m = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    string stringM = m.ToString();

    if (radioButton1.Checked && radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error. Student cannot receive Tier 1 and Tier 2.");
        Form1 NewForm = new Form1();
        NewForm.Show();
        this.Dispose(false);
    }
    switch (stringM)
    {
        case "Distinguished Freshman":
            MessageBox.Show("####");
            break;
        case "Presidential Scholarship (Tier 1: $9,500)":
                if(radioButton1.Checked)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("P1H183S 9500");
                    }
                else if(radioButton2.Checked)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("P1H183S 9000");
                    }
            break;
        case "University Centurium (Tier 1: $7,000)":
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("1UC183S 7000");
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("1UC183S 6500");
            }
            break;
        case "Red and Gray (Tier 1: $4,000)":
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("1RG183S 4000");
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("1RG183S 3500");
            }
            break;
        case "Reddie Achievement":
            MessageBox.Show("RAF 183S ####");
            break;
        case "Transfer (Tier 1: $4,500)":
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("P1H182S 9500");
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("P1H182S 9000");
            }
            break;
        case "Transfer (Tier 2: $4,000)":
            break;
    }
}
```

I want the user to use a ComboBox to select the scholarship name, then choose Tier 1 or Tier 2 if necessary, then choose 4, 6, or 8 semesters if (AND ONLY IF) the scholarship is a transfer scholarship. There is a clear button to clear the entire form at the bottom and a submit button. When the submit button is selectd, I want it to print a string that can be copied/pasted. (Will a MessageBox work fine for this, or does anyone have any better suggestions?)

Thank you all so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Wiring up the radio buttons `CheckedChanged` event will signal when the radio button changes. Just guessing from the `Switch` `Case` items… it may be more prudent to initially have the combo box disabled or only have the items that belong when “both” radio buttons are NOT checked. Then when the user “checks” the “Tier 1” radio button, THEN the combo box would only contain items pertaining to “Tier 1”… etc. In other words, the checked radio buttons will determine “what” values are in the combo box. Just a thought.

Comment: @JohnG The only way that I have found so far to add new items to the combo box is by right-clicking and selecting "Edit Items". Is there a way that you know of where I could add the items within the code? For example, if I went with your suggestion and said that Tier 1 would include x, y, and z scholarships and Tier 2 would include a, b, and c scholarships. Could I create the combo box items within tier1radB.CheckChanged and tier2radB.CheckChanged?

Comment: You may want to use [`RadioButtonList`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41355419/3110834).