# RadioButton changes its Height when addeed to Form.Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I create a number of RadioButtons programatically in a loop. I set a few of its properties and in the end I add the newly created RadioButton to the Form.Controls list.
Before I add the RadioButton to the Form.Controls, its Height property is 24.
One line after I add the RadioButton to the Form.Controls, its Height property is 29.
Here is the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRadioButtons; i++)
{
    RadioButton currentRadioButton = new RadioButton();
    currentRadioButton.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
    currentRadioButton.Name = "radioButton" + (i + 1).ToString();
    currentRadioButton.Text = currentRadioButton.Name;
    currentRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
    int currentRadioButtonHeight = currentRadioButton.Height; // 24
    this.Controls.Add(currentRadioButton);
    currentRadioButtonHeight = currentRadioButton.Height; // 29
}
```

I do not understand how adding a control to Form.Controls changes the value of the control's height.
Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't arrange controls yourself. Let a `FlowLayoutPanel` or a `TableLayoutPanel` do it for you.

Comment: Also you may want to take a look at [`RadioButtonList`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41355419/3110834) control.

Answer (score 0):

I found out!
the statement:

```
currentRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
```

changes the height.
If the statement is:

```
currentRadioButton.AutoSize = false;
```

the height does not change.

Comment: This will prevent the correct positioning of the Text in relation to the Radio Button. Plus, if/when the font is scaled, due to the display settings of a user, the text will be, possbily, cut out or re-positioned. You should take the advice that Reza Aghaei gave you.