# Is there a better way to run through radio buttons in an if statement?

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement

I am new to C#. I want to find a faster way to run through a large number of radio buttons to see if they are checked or not. Here is my code now:

```
if(radibutton1.checked == true && radiobutton2.checked== true) {
   //Do something
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, because, with all my radio buttons, there will be many if statements and I worry that the way I am doing it now will slow down my app.
[image]

Comment: Can you state that is it WinForms or WPF?

Comment: WinForms sorry for ....

Comment: You can rely on [`RadioButtonList`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41355419/3110834). It makes the UI and code a bit cleaner. Also getting rid of those if statements completely depends on what you are trying to do with the selected values. You may be able to pass those values to a function without having any if statement.

Comment: @RezaAghaei agree, I skimmed too quick! (thought it was Checkboxes). Reopened :)

Comment: @MaeveMaeveov Without knowing what you are going to do with those radio buttons it's hard to share some useful idea. However in general I think the question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you have more than say 4  radio buttons (in a group), I think it is better to use a combobox or a list instead.

Otherwise for maintenance purpose, it will be better to somehow use a loop. There are many way to get the controls.

- You could initialize an array that contains all controls in a group. Something like:

  ```
  var group1radios = new RadioButton[] { radio1, radio2, radio 3, radio4 };
  ```
- You could enumerate controls on your form and somehow detect if the control is a radio button belonging to your group (by position, groupbox, tag, name, consecutive radios…).
- You could create a panel that contains only radio buttons.

Comment: Perfect i create loop with for and convert something to string and it works Great Job