# How to display values of radio button onto data grid view table

Tags: c#, winforms

There are 2 radio buttons: one for appointment and one for task. I was wondering how I could get the value of the other radio button task if it is selected. At the moment even if I select the radio button of task it will still give me the value of appointment. Is there an Or function I can use? Only one button can be selected either appointment/task.

```
int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = radioAppointment.Text;
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = textLocation.Text;
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = dateTimePicker1.Text;
```

Comment: Radio buttons have a `Checked` property indicating if they are selected...

Comment: You may want to take a look at [`RadioButtonList`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41355419/3110834).

Answer (score 0):

```
    int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    string val;
    if(radioAppointment.checked==true){
    val=radioAppointment.Text;
    }
if(radioTask.checked==true){
    val=radioTask.Text;
    }
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = val;
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = textLocation.Text;
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = dateTimePicker1.Text;
```